# EIF slam algorithm implementation as per Probabilistic Robotics

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, localization, jacobian, artificial-intelligence

I want to implement EIF slam from Probabilistic Robotics Table 11.2. This is the algorithm for EIF slam.
[image]

To construct $\Omega and \xi$ matrix I write down a Java code. Here is my code

```
public class Part1Jama {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Matrix Bigomega = new Matrix(11116,11116);//last 15 row and column define landmarks x and y axis
    Matrix omega = new Matrix(11116,11116);
    Matrix BigXi = new Matrix(11116, 1);
    Matrix Xi = new Matrix(11116, 1);


    int i = 0, i1 = 0, k1 = 0, k2 = 0, l = 0, l1 = 0,k3=0,j=0;
    double[] timex = new double[11101];//11101 odometer data denoting by u_1;
    double[] xcoa = new double[11101];
    double[] ycoa = new double[11101];
    double[]thetacoa=new double[11101];

    double[] landx = new double[3095];//3095 measurment data z
    double[] landy = new double[3095];
    double[] timeya = new double[3095];
    double[] codea = new double[3095];
    double[] rangea = new double[3095];
    double[] bearinga = new double[3095];
    Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("/home/froboticscse/IdeaProjects/UJMPtest/src/main/java/measurmentF.txt"));
    Scanner y = new Scanner(new File("/home/froboticscse/IdeaProjects/UJMPtest/src/main/java/uniquemeasure.txt"));


    while (x.hasNext()) {
//Data from odometry data file which consist of time,forward velocity angular velocity
        double time = x.nextDouble();
        double xco = x.nextDouble();
        double yco = x.nextDouble();
        double theta=x.nextDouble();
        timex[i] = time;
        xcoa[i] = xco;
        ycoa[i] = yco;
        thetacoa[i]=theta;
        i++;
    }

    while (y.hasNext()) {
//Data from measurement file consist of time,correspondence Number(landmark number),range,bearing 
        double timey = y.nextDouble();
        double code = y.nextDouble();
        double range = y.nextDouble();
        double bearing = y.nextDouble();
        timeya[i1] = timey;
        codea[i1] = code;
        rangea[i1] = range;
        bearinga[i1] = bearing;

        i1++;

    }



    while(k1<timex.length-1) {
        if (timex[k1] < timeya[k2]) {

            omega.set( k1, k1,1);
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,-1);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1,-1);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,1);

            Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
            omega.set( k1, k1,0);// clear value store in omega
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,0);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1,0);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,0);

            Xi.set( k1, 0,-(ycoa[k1]));
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,ycoa[k1]);
            BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
            Xi.set( k1, 0,0); //clear value store in Xi
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);


        } 
// //For line number 10 to 20 as per algorithm
else if (timex[k1] == timeya[k2]) {
            landy[l1] = ycoa[k1] + rangea[k2] * (Math.cos(bearinga[k2] + thetacoa[k1]));
            omega.set( k1, k1,1);
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,-1);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1,-1);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,1);
            Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
            omega.set( k1, k1,0);
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,0);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1,0);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,0);

            Xi.set( k1, 0,-(ycoa[k1]));
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,ycoa[k1]);
            BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
            Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);
            if (codea[k2] == 90.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11101, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11101, 11101,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11101,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11101, k1,0);
                omega.set(11101, 11101,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11101,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);


            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 18.0) {
                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11102, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11102, 11102,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11102,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11102, k1,0);
                omega.set(11102, 11102,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11102,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 81.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11103, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11103, 11103,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11103,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11103, k1,0);
                omega.set(11103, 11103,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11103,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 9.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11104, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11104, 11104,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11104,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11104, k1,0);
                omega.set(11104, 11104,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11104,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 25.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11105, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11105, 11105,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11105,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11105, k1,0);
                omega.set(11105, 11105,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11105,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 61.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11106, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11106, 11106,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11106,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11106, k1,0);
                omega.set(11106, 11106,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11106,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 72.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11107, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11107, 11107,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11107,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11107, k1,0);
                omega.set(11107, 11107,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11107,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 36.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11108, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11108, 11108,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11108,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11108, k1,0);
                omega.set(11108, 11108,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11108,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 70.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11109, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11109, 11109,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11109,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11109, k1,0);
                omega.set(11109, 11109,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11109,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 27.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11110, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11110, 11110,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11110,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11110, k1,0);
                omega.set(11110, 11110,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11110,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 54.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11111, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11111, 11111,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11111,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11111, k1,0);
                omega.set(11111, 11111,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11111,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 16.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11112, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11112, 11112,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11112,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11112, k1,0);
                omega.set(11112, 11112,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11112,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 45.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11113, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11113, 11113,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11113,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11113, k1,0);
                omega.set(11113, 11113,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11113,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 7.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11114, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11114, 11114,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11114,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11114, k1,0);
                omega.set(11114, 11114,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11114,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }
            else if (codea[k2] == 63.0) {

                omega.set(k1, k1,1);
                omega.set( 11115, k1,-1);
                omega.set(11115, 11115,1);
                omega.set(k1, 11115,-1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.set(k1, k1,0);
                omega.set( 11115, k1,0);
                omega.set(11115, 11115,0);
                omega.set(k1, 11115,0);

                Xi.set( k1, 0,((-landy[l1]) + ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,(landy[l1] + ycoa[k1]));
                BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

            }

            if(k2<timeya.length-1) {
                k2++;

            }
            l++;
        } else  if(timex[k1] > timeya[k2]) {
            omega.set(k1, k1,1);
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,-1);
            omega.set(k1 + 1, k1,-1);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,1);
            Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
            omega.set(k1, k1,0);
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,0);
            omega.set(k1 + 1, k1,0);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,0);

            Xi.set( k1, 0,-(ycoa[k1]));
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,ycoa[k1]);
            BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
            Xi.set( k1, 0,0);
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);

        }
        k1++;
    }
    Bigomega.set(0,0,2);

    Matrix mu=Bigomega.inverse().times(BigXi);
    mu.print(3,6);


}
```

}

In the java code xcoa,ycoa,thetacoa get from line no.5(Algorithm EIF-construct). I create another java file to save the values that I get from line no: 5.Then I use it here. I am not very sure how to construct line no:6 and 7 so I assume that our world is noise free and use 1 and -1 for to represent it between two pose. Say , Robot go from $x_t to x_{t+1}$ so the cell between them the diagonal cell represent with 1 and off diagonal -1.

```
while(k1<timex.length-1) {
        if (timex[k1] < timeya[k2]) {

            omega.set( k1, k1,1);
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,-1);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1,-1);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,1);

            Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
            omega.set( k1, k1,0); //clear value store in omega
            omega.set(k1, k1 + 1,0);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1,0);
            omega.set( k1 + 1, k1 + 1,0);

            Xi.set( k1, 0,-(ycoa[k1]));// construct $\xi$ vector for y co - ordinate. Alternation of line 19. As fail to understand how to create $\mu_{tx},\mu_{ty},\mu_{t\theta},\mu_{jx}\mu_{jy}$
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,ycoa[k1]);
            BigXi = BigXi.plus(Xi);
            Xi.set( k1, 0,0); //clear value store is xi
            Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,0);


        }
```

90.0,54.0,27.0,81.0.... they are the landmark numbers. As per my code same code run thrice for x,y,theta and then plot all of them to get a map and path. The code I write here is run for y  co because $\xi$ is set as *** Xi.set( k1, 0,-(ycoa[k1]));
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,ycoa[k1]);**  If I write  down  Xi.set( k1, 0,-**(xcoa[k1])***);
                Xi.set(k1 + 1, 0,***xcoa[k1]***); it will give me x coordinates. So I modify this code in this way.

The problem with this code is ***Matrix inversion*** is difficult.

Looking for the suggestion how to implement the code as describe in algorithm?

What is the need of Algorithm EIF_reduce as per table 11.3? I have only 15 landmark. So I calculate $\mu $ at the end of this code block. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm having trouble following along with your question, but you say `the problem with this code is Matrix inversion is difficult`, but I'm not seeing an matrix inversion happening here offhand. I'm assuming the code and `if...elseif` statements in your code are all for the `for all observed features` line in the algorithm?

Comment: Yes there is a matrix inversion just before the last line. Matrix mu=Bigomega.inverse().times(BigXi);

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Encipher, but I'm afraid that questions asking for code are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given coding problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please try to include what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.